# Function returns promise object instead of value (async/await)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I got this code using the async/await :

```
function _getSSID(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      NetworkInfo.getSSID(ssid => resolve(ssid))
   })
}

async function getSSID(){
   let mySSID =  await _getSSID()
   if (mySSID == "error") {
     return 'The value I want to return'
   }
}
```

And `getSSID()` is equal to this : 
[image]

Looks like the `getSSID()` function will always return a promise. How can I get `"The value I want to return"` in plain text ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `getSSID().then(value => { /* do something with value */ })`

Comment: You could call it inside another async function and await for the result.  Asynchoronous effect is contagious. Once you have something async it makes async everything it touches.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko that's not poisonous, that's just contagious ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts but what if I want to create a variable with the value of what I want to return ? I can't just put `getSSID().then(value => { return value })`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts true true. :)

Comment: @Lawris please refer to the duplicate question, it explains everything.

Comment: @Lawris: you can have a variable: `var result = await getSSID()`. Just the context you call it from has to be `async`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Is there no way to create that variable without having it in an async context?

Answer (score 20):

Declaring a function `async` means that it will return the `Promise`. To turn the `Promise` into a value, you have two options.

The "normal" option is to use `then()` on it:

```
getSSID().then(value => console.log(value));
```

You can also use `await` on the function:

```
const value = await getSSID();
```

The catch with using `await` is it too must be inside of an `async` function.

At some point, you'll have something at the top level, which can either use the first option, or can be a self-calling function like this:

```
((async () => {
    const value = await getSSID();
    console.log(value);
})()).catch(console.error):
```

If you go with that, be sure to have a `catch()` on that function to catch any otherwise uncaught exceptions.

You can't use `await` at the top-level.

Comment: While I hope top-level `await` never makes the cut (see [top-level `await` is a footgun](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221)), it is currently [a stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/MylesBorins/proposal-top-level-await).

Comment: Indeed. I've read that, and I tend to agree with the gist you linked. That's why I like the anonymous self-calling async function to kick things off. Still mostly at the top level, with the benefits of not really being there.

Comment: It doesn't actually solve my problem, I want to create a variable that will be equal to the value I want to return with the promise.

Comment: It should. If `mySSID === 'error'`, then the `value` in all of the examples above will equal `"The value I want to return"`